# How to stop Django from using response csrf token for the next request

Tags: django, django-settings, django-csrf

I need to configure django csrf tokens such that every request has to have a new token. I put the following code inside my views:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token 
def login(request):
    rotate_token(request)
```

This seems to work in changing the token for each request. The issue is that whenever I go to a new page, the request token uses the value of the response token from the previous page:

[image: values from the first page]

[image: values on clicking the next page]

My settings file:

```
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_EXPIRY = 60*60*24*30
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_USE_HISTORY = True

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost'

SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 720
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 15768000
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
REQUEST_LOGGING_ENABLE_COLORIZE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/myproject'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1800
```

How do I change my code so that the CSRF token from the request is different from the previous response?

Comment: The token is generated _server side_, why and **how** do you expect the client to send a _new_ token (which the server will create in the new request according to your code) while making the request?

Comment: I believe this is a secure implementation but was flagged as insecure by my security department.

Comment: Tell your security department they talk about doing something impossible. The client and server are two _different_ entities, expecting the client to predict what new token the server would (randomly) generate each request is not possible. The max you can have is each response having a new token (Already this is excessive, if the client runs multiple tabs, likely they are going to get CSRF errors this way) as you already do.